# Magento 2 Invoice pdf attachement to sales order email

Tags: magento2, order-email

I have created a mass complete action in sales order. I want to send invoice pdf attachment once the order get status as complete. I am able to get that job done using createAttachment at the event  **"sales_order_save_after"** for single order email.

```
$this->message->createAttachment(
    $pdf->render(),
    \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
    'invoice-'.$invoiceId.'.pdf'
);
$this->orderSender->send($order);
```

Here `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Message $message` and `$this->message = $message;` passed in construct.

It works fine for single order but when I am trying to send while mass complete status, it attach invoice pdf to first order email only. All next order emails are getting send without invoice attachment. Please help me if anyone have idea on it.

Edit :

Attaching whole code below: 1. etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="my_invoice_attachment_observer" instance="My\Company\Observer\Invoiceattachment" />        
    </event>
</config>
```

2. **Observer/Invoiceattachment.php**

`

```
    namespace My\Company\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;
    use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;
    use Magento\Framework\Mail\Message;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

    class Invoiceattachment implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $message;
    protected $orderFactory;
    protected $_fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var OrderSender
     */
    protected $orderSender;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        Message $message,
        Logger $logger,
        OrderSender $orderSender,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        if ($order instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) {
           if($order->getState() == 'complete') {
           $fullOrder = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());
           $_invoices = $fullOrder->getInvoiceCollection();
           $invoiceId = FALSE;
            if($_invoices){
                foreach($_invoices as $invoice){
                    $invoiceId = $invoice->getId();
                }
            }
           if ($invoiceId) {
                $invoice = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface')->get($invoiceId);
                if ($invoice) {
                    $pdf = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice')->getPdf([$invoice]);
                    $date = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
                    try {   
                        if($pdf->render())
                            {
                                if( 
                                    $this->message->createAttachment(
                                    $pdf->render(),
                                    \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                                    \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                                    \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                                    'invoice-'.$invoiceId.'.pdf'
                                )){

                                    $this->orderSender->send($order);

                                }
                            }

                    }catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
                    }
                }
             }
           }
        }
        return $this;
     }
}`
```

Comment: Just to understand correctly: do you added a mass action in order grid to set selected orders in complete status?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added new mass action to complete orders at sales order grid in backend. It generates invoice, shipment and send emails while this action.

Comment: Why are you using an observer on the event sales_order_save_after to create a mass action?

Comment: Event is not being used to create mass action, mass action code is in separate module. This event is just used to attach the pdf invoice attachment to oder. :)

Comment: Ok, so why you don't put the code to attach the pdf invoice directly in the mass action code?

Comment: I tried by putting it there but it is creating same issue. It is sending pdf to first order in mass action, all other order emails are without invoice pdf.

Comment: Ok, so i think you have to debug `$this->message` before send order, until you see that all orders have the attachement.